# C++ Semantical Errors when Compiling

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble programming in C++ because, when I'm working a project, I get a bunch of semantical errors that shouldn't be there.

When a colleague of mine started a project and sent it to me, I got errors in my computer, and she didn't.

This had happened to me before. I started working for a project and it appeared a similar error. Then, on my teacher's computer, it vanished.

I formatted my computer recently and am now using Windows 8 64-bits. I use Eclipse Juno C++ 64 bits, but also tried it on Indigo and it didn't work. My compiler is MinGW 9.4.

I guess there must be some configuration problem. Probably with the building.

I would like a solution that didn't deactivate the errors I find useful.

Can someone please help me? =)

**Edit:** Almost all the errors that appear are

> Method X could not be resolved.

or

> Invalid arguments

**Edit2:**

> Probably your colleague is using a Microsoft compiler which are notably more lax in allowing illegal code compared to for example gcc, which is likely the compiler being used by MinGW. – Mark B

My colleague and professor are also using Eclipse and MinGW.

Comment: Post the errors or nobody can help you.

Comment: Probably your colleague is using a Microsoft compiler which are notably more lax in allowing illegal code compared to for example gcc, which is likely the compiler being used by MinGW.

Comment: That's a fantastic story, it has mystery and intrigue but it lacks romance.

Answer (score 4):

First off, they're not called semantical errors. Semantics refers to the meaning of your program, indicating a logic bug. I assume you're talking about compiler errors, which generally refer to incorrect *syntax*.

Second there are a number of reasons that you may get different errors and warnings on different computers. Some compilers and versions of compilers are stricter about conformance than others. Some have bugs. You may have compiler specific extensions that aren't recognized by other compilers. You may have different flags set, which will affect the number and type of errors you get. (An extreme example is -wall -werror, but even stuff like compiling in C++03 vs C++11 will cause a number of differences).

Another major cause of errors that differs from computer to computer is library placement. C and C++ compilers/linkers are very finnicky about making sure you have all the right headers and libraries in the right places with the right paths set.

Comment: I said they were semantical errors because the error "Type" was "Semantic Error".

As for turning warnings into errors, in other computers the Projects don't have any warnings. Only in mine...

Comment: Compiler errors can be semantic. `void* x = 42;` has a semantic error: the types do not match. The syntax, OTOH, is perfect.